# JUnit test running via ant returns No persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, ant

I have jsf aplication with connection to PostgreSQL. Also I wrote a test for checking this connection. It works fine when I run this test via maven, but it fails with "No persistence provider for EntityManager named myUnitSuper", when I try to use my Ant target "test".
This is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Web3">
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="target" location="target"/>
    <property name="classes" location="${target}/classes"/>
    <property name="build" location="${target}/jar"/>
    <property name="doc" location="${target}/doc"/>
    <property name="team" location="${target}/team"/>
    <property name="meta" location="${src}/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
    <property name="test-classes" location="${target}/test-classes"/>

    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="libs">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <delete dir="${classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <copy todir="${target}/classes">
            <fileset dir="${src}/main/resources"/>
        </copy>
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includeantruntime="false">
            <src path="${src}"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="build.classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <mkdir dir="${test-classes}"/>
        <move todir="${test-classes}">
            <filelist dir="${classes}">
                <file name="QueriesTest.class"/>
            </filelist>
        </move>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="compile">
        <property name="jarName" value="Web3"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
        <jar destfile="${build}/${jarName}.jar" basedir="${classes}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${target}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="build">
        <mkdir dir="${target}/reports"/>
        <junit printsummary="true" haltonfailure="true" showoutput="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${test-classes}"/>
                <pathelement location="${classes}"/>
            </classpath>
            <test name="QueriesTest" todir="${target}/reports"/>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

Test class:

```
public class QueriesTest {
    final EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myUnitSuper").createEntityManager();

    @Test
    public void testDB() {
        long id = 1;
        Shot shot = new Shot(id, true, 2, 3, 4, new Date(123), 1, "#FFFFFF");
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(shot);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        Shot find = entityManager.find(Shot.class, id);
        assert(shot.equals(find));
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myUnitSuper" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.example.web3.entities.Shot</class>
        <class>com.example.web3.db.DatabaseManager</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" /> <!-- DB Driver -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" /> <!-- BD Mane -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="aleksgright" /> <!-- DB User -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="230921" /> <!-- DB Password -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I need to run my test with "ant test". I guess the problem is that my testClass dont have a path to persistence.xml ot persistence.xml is located in a wrong place, but I can't figure out what I should do.